# How to pass value in URL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, routes, getmethod

I want to click on "View Detail" button and go to another page "/viewdeail/id=2", here id=2 is comes from the View Detail button click. So far I prepare this snippet.

**Controller:**

```
public function schooldetailviewid($school_id)
     {
        return view('viewdeail/school_id={$school_id}', compact('school_id'));
     }
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/viewdeail/school_id={school_id}', 'ViewController@schooldetailviewid')->name('schooldetail');
```

I am very much confused about how to solve this.

Comment: `/viewdetail/{school_id}` play around with `school_id`,and `return view('schooldetail')->with(['school_id'=>$school_id]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Laravel, if you need to pass a required parameter in your route, you need to specify it into your `routes/web.php` file, and get it from your controller action.

This the common way to do that:

```php
// routes/web.php

Route::get('/viewdeail/{schoolId}', 'ViewController@details')->name('schooldetail');
```

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/ViewController.php

class ViewController extends Controller {

    ...

    public function details($schoolId) {
        // your view located in ressources/views folder
        return view('viewdeail/', compact('schoolId'));
    }

}
```

Now, if you want to just get parameters like `domain.tld/viewdeail?schoolId=3` for example, you need to remove `{schoolId}` in the previously defined route in the `routes/web.php` file, and edit your controller and proceed like that:

```php
// app/Http/Controllers/ViewController.php

use Illuminate\Http\Request; // we need the Request class, so import it

class ViewController extends Controller {

    ...

    public function details(Request $request) {
        $schoolId = $request->query('schoolId');

        // your view located in ressources/views folder
        return view('viewdeail/', compact('schoolId'));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are passing the parameter this way `/viewdeail?id=2`

Then in your controller you need to use the `Request` Object to fetch it:

```
public function schooldetailviewid(Request $request)
{ 

    $school_id = $request->get('id');

    return view("viewdeatil/school_id=$school_id", compact('school_id'));
}
```

Please review the Laravel routing documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#route-parameters

Comment: to get in this way need to be `uri?id=2`,isn't it?

Comment: Yes that is how you would pass the param

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this in a couple of ways.

you could do,

`$school_id = $request->get('id');`

or

`$school_id = YourModel::find('$id');`

you can use Request to fetch your data

**Controller**

```
public function schooldetailviewid(Request $request)
{ 

$school_id = $request->get('id');

return view("viewdeatil/school_id/$school_id", compact('school_id'));
}
```

**Route**

your route should look like this;

```
Route::get('/viewdeail/school_id/{school_id}', 'ViewController@schooldetailviewid')->name('schooldetail');
```

**Blade**
your a tag should look like this;

```
<a href="{{route('schooldetail', $school_id->id)}}">getDetails</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Route::group(['as'=>'admin.','prefix'=>'admin','namespace'=>'Admin','middleware'=>['auth','admin']], function (){

    Route::resource('category','CategoryController');

}); 

public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::latest()->get();
        return view('admin.category.index',compact('categories'));
    }
```